# how to generate url for public folder in mailers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

In the mailer template i want to generate correct url for the path public/system/test.png

Suppose in the mailer template

```
 <%= link_to k, "/system/test.png" %> <br />
```

how can i generate the full path such as

```
https://www.example.com/system/test.png
```

I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are trying to ask - why not just add the full url inside the link_to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to k, root_url + 'system/test.png' %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add assets host in your production.rb

```
config.action_controller.asset_host = 'https://www.example.com'
```

You can fine more about assets [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= link_to k, asset_url('/public/system/test.jpeg')%>
```

this will generate link as:-

```
https://example.com/public/system/test.jpeg
```

and your html code will generate like this: --

```
<a href="https://example.com/public/system/test.jpeg">k</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to the following

This code is tested

```
<%= link_to image_tag("/system/test.png"), root_url %>
```

`image_tag` by default located the public folder and `root_url` will redirect  to the home page after click image

Or solution two

```
<a href="<%= root_url %>">
    <%= image_tag "#{Rails.root}/public/system/test.png" %>
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use `<%= link_to k, "#{Rails.root}/system/test.png" %>`
Hope this is what you are looking for.